# Java open folder does return the selected folder

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I use the following code I found on internet to select a folder:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();  
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setDialogTitle("Select destination folder");
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  jTextField2.setText(chooser.getCurrentDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
} else {
  System.out.println("No Selection ");
}
```

However if for example I browse to

> "C:\testfolder\"

then the

> "chooser.getCurrentDirectory().getAbsolutePath()"

returns

> c:\

How can I resolve this to return **"C:\testfolder\"** ?

Comment: Try using `chooser.getSelectedFile()` instead of `chooser. getCurrentDirectory()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `chooser.getSelectedFile()` instead of `chooser. getCurrentDirectory()`. You might want have a look at [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details.

You not asking the dialog for the currently selected file, but where the dialog was set to start from